# How to format django timezone.now()

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

The default format of django timezone.now() **example** `Aug. 15, 2021, 1:00pm` how to convert this into `2021-8-15` thanks in advance!

Here is my **models.py**

```
publish= models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
```

i tried this:

```
publish= models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

but its not working , here is my html that i want to render my timezone:

```
<div class="main-banner header-text">
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="owl-banner owl-carousel">
  {% for data in dataset %}
  {% if forloop.counter >= 4 and forloop.counter <= 6 %}
   <div class="item">
    <img src="{{data.image.url}}" alt="{{data.blog_title}}">
     <div class="item-content">
       <div class="main-content">
         <div class="meta-category">
           <span>{{catlist.cat}}</span>
         </div>
         <a  href="{% url 'blogapp:blog' _id=data.slug %}"><h4>{{data.blog_title}}</h4></a>
         <ul class="post-info">
           <li><a>{{data.publish}}</a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `timezone.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DateTime field stores a datetime object, not a string, therefore you cannot format the string in the database. You need to format it in the template:

```
<li><a>{{ data.publish|date:'%Y-%m-%d' }}</a></li>
```